# Authentication issue in uploading videos to youtube using android application

Tags: java, android, authentication, youtube, youtube-api

Check out My Complete Code for uploading Video on youtube [click here](http://pastebin.com/E3Hb4Zse)

The problem is ,i can upload the video from SD card n it takes file name but main issue is authentication for youtube . Its not gone be happening and i am getting error .Infact the service from youtube is not gone be directing my user account  .I feel trouble over authentication .

We are using gdata client library .
Error Details :

```
     E/dalvikvm(682): Could not find class 
    'com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaStreamSource', referenced from method 
     com.google.gdata.client.media.MediaService.getMediaResource
```

Can anyone help me in authentication n get service from youtube . Please suggest me .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer for it .I just used youtube direct resumable Api details for solution.